# Can someone tell me if this script is correct?

Tags: characters, character-identification

I'm trying to write in full cursive with my own personal style and this is one of my first letterings.

I'm quite happy and I think that it does look readable, but I'm afraid that the two long line I left in the middle of the first sentence could break its logic. The long line in the second one should divide this "有形" from this "以太".
I found many different way to write the same Hanzi in cursive and I'm afraid I made up a mess mixing styles that don't match among them... but I almost like the final result and I hope it can be considered a good work.

According to you is this strange or wrong? 
Do the Hanzi have a logical and coherent style?
Can you easily understand what it means?

[image]

I hope not to be off topic, if so I really apologize. I have no intention to waste anyone's time, I'd just like to have an opinion from people I can trust.

Comment: "以太" is ok but I cannot easily recognize other words. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Hanzi have many different writing styles and there is no right or wrong as long as you can understand what you are writing.

For me, it looks like *Caoshu* style. But unfortunately that is one of the hard-to-read styles in Hanzi. I only recognize 4 out of 8 of them. (if I am counting right)

As for 太, it is not easy to recognize. The small *dot* should be more upwards, at least in between the *two swipes*.

If this is for display purpose, that is fine. But not in communication purpose as not so many Chinese these days could read *Caoshu*.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get a *Caoshu* copybook. You could borrow it from a [library](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=Cao%20shu%20zi%20tie&qt=owc_search), or buy it on Ebay ([link for a shopper](https://www.ebay.com/sch/shishizhangpainting/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_ipg=&_from=)) or Amazon, even on [Taobao](https://s.taobao.com/search?q=%E8%8D%89%E4%B9%A6%E5%AD%97%E5%B8%96&type=p&tmhkh5=&spm=a21wu.10013406.a2227oh.d100&from=sea_1_searchbutton&catId=100) (for international shipping). 
*Caoshu* copybook 草书字帖 Cǎoshū Zìtiè 
Beside, go to [Cidianwang](https://www.cidianwang.com/shufa/wen6677_cs.htm) search *Caoshu* font of a character.

Answer (score 0):

This is okay as long as you draw it like a piece of art xD
(Yeah, try to convey the feeling by strokes, stop worrying if that's correct or not)
Then it will be your style.
(I'm not saying you can't use some caoshu reference)

Answer (score -2):

I can't easily recognize words in Chinese scripts, I guess my father too or my grandfather too, so it's ok about readable.

I can't tell this is written by Chinese or foreign by just looking at it, but Chinese people who do scripts would write traditional Chinese character instead of simplified even in China mainland.

And 太 is not that being written like the ones I saw before.